# How do I turn off this keyboard popup when I press L3 on a game controller

Tags: on-screen-keyboard

[image: image description here]

Does anyone recognized this popup keyboard and know how to disable it? It appears when I press press L3 on any controller and I don't know the source of it. My Steam popup keyboard is disabled and its also not part of Windows 11. I use DS4 but I am unaware of any popup keyboard implementation.

Comment: Post this comment as an answer, as it contains the actual solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it did end up being steam that was running in the background. I had to expose the hidden items on my task bar to shut steam down. The keyboard looks different from any pic I have seen of the steam keyboard in forums and must have been updated. I followed instructions about disabling it through steam controller settings but that did not work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).